# How to get relation value before ember resolve the relation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have three models:

```
App.Model1 = DS.Model.extend({
   ref2: DS.hasMany('model2', {async: true})
});

App.Model2 = DS.Model.extend({
   ref3: DS.belongsTo('model3', {async: true})
});

App.Model3 = DS.Model.extend({
   someProp: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The thing is I need to fetch the three models in one route but I only want what is necessary. Which means I need to fetch `Model1`, `Model2` that are referenced by `Model1` and finally `Model3` which are referenced by the `Model2`.

Ember-data does a good job because it resolves the `hasMany` relationship in one XHR request. The problem is that I want to do something like this (in the `beforeModel` for example):

```
return this.store.find('model1', model_id).then(function(data) {
    return data.get('ref2').then(function(arrayData) {
        var array = [];

        arrayData.forEach(function(item) {
            array.push(item.get('ref3'));
        });

        return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(array);
     });
 });
```

But doing such thing make ember-data to do as many xhr request as the number of item in the array. If I could get the id of the referenced object before it resolve the relation, then I would be able to get all the `Model3` objects in one request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of this on the back end, it'd be easier to address this server side, returning the related record in the original response.  This is especially true if you are always requesting the records together, in the fashion that you are above.  Additionally you'd change your relationships to not be async.

```
{
  model1s:[
    {
       id:1,
       ref2: [1,2]
    },
    {
       id:2,
       ref2: [3,4]
    }
  ],
  model2s:[
    {
       id:1,
       ref3: [1,2]
    },
    {
       id:2,
       ref3: [3,4]
    }  
    .....
  ],
  model3s:[
   ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew you would have said that. I should have precise that they're not always requested together which explain why I wanted to do what I'm asking.